# What is a live environment when it comes to database?

Tags: database, live, environment

This term, "live environment", has been mentioned in someone's answer.

I tried to google this term, but I can't find clearer explanations..

It seems a bit similar to real-time computing or live database, which I don't know a thing about..well I just have a feeling that it is quite different from those terms..

Comment: To me, it would mean a database that is being actively used by an application, by real users, for real work. Not a Development instance, test instance, or staging environment.  If you could give some more context as to how the phrase was used, we might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: What answer was it mentioned in? It would help if we had some context, but I'd agree with @BradleyUffner based on the limited information you provided here. (Context is relevant; for instance, the term *clean environment* means different things when you're asking about the planet itself and a microprocessor plant or surgical operating room.)

Comment: Like I have problem when using SQL to insert data into a database in PHP, and there was people saying what I coded will get hacked related to live environment